# Why does VS2005 skip execution of lines when debugging managed C++ without optimizations?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, c++-cli

I ran into a rather odd behavior that I don't even know how to start describing.
I wrote a piece of managed C++ code that makes calls to native methods.

A (very) simplified version of the code would look like this (I know it looks like a full native function, just assume there is managed stuff being done all over the place):

```
int somefunction(ptrHolder x)
{
  // the accessptr method returns a native pointer
  if (x.accessptr() != nullptr) // I tried this with nullptr, NULL, 0)
  {
    try
    {
      x->doSomeNativeVeryImportantStuff(); // or whatever, doesn't matter
    }
    catch (SomeCustomExceptionClass &)
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  SomeOtherNativeClass::doStaticMagic();

  return 1;
}
```

I compiled this code without optimizations using the /clr flag (VS.NET 2005, SP2) and when running it in the debugger I get to the if statement, since the pointer is actually null, I don't enter the if, but surprisingly, the cursor jumps directly to the return 1 statement, ignoring the doStaticMagic() method completely!!!

When looking at the assembly code, I see that it really jumps directly to that line.
If I force the debugger to enter the if block, I also jump to the return 1 statement after I press F10.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks,
Ariel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try checking that code is actually emitted for the SomeOtherNativeClass::doStaticMagic(); line? Perhaps the compiler couldn't find it (or finds an empty function or something like that) and therefore skips it.

Second idea: Perhaps you are comparing two things which can't be compared by using nullptr. So you get an exception, which is caught and causes you to exit the method directly.

Comment: You were right about this. Managed C++ behaves weirdly when an exception is thrown and not handled, the execution jumps to the last return line, what makes it look confusing in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the [Just My Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(VS.80).aspx) feature in VS2005? It's enabled by default.

From MSDN:

> Sometimes, while you are debugging,
>   you might want to look at only the
>   code you have written and ignore other
>   code, such as system calls. You can do
>   this with Just My Code debugging. Just
>   My Code hides non-user code so that it
>   does not appear in the debugger
>   windows. When you step, the debugger
>   steps through any non-user code but
>   does not stop in it.
>
> To distinguish user code ("My Code")
>   from non-user code, Just My Code looks
>   at three things: DBG Files, PDB files,
>   and optimization.